# Place New Instance of marker for each touch on Map in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

Place New Instance of marker for each touch on Map without removing previous marker from map

Comment: Have you attempted anything? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Ewald I  inherited my Fragment from GoogleMap.IonMapClickListener and override d OnMapClick..at touch I'm getting marker..but when I touch new location first marker is getting disappeared

Comment: Can you post the code to show the marker?  I have an app that displays multiple markers.

Comment: @Ewald  map.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(point).SetTitle("test marker")).SetIcon(Android.Gms.Maps.Model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(Android.Gms.Maps.Model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueAzure));

Comment: That's interesting, I have more or less the same code and get separate markers.  Let me try your code.

Comment: Using your code, I get multiple markers.

Comment: @Ewald ok Ewald I will try it once and post the full code

Comment: That's great - maybe I can see something that's different in the full code @Divya

Comment: @Ewald  multiple markers are coming... I had put map.Clear() that's the reason previous markers was getting removed

Comment: @Ewald  can you tell me how to join multiple markers or draw polygon out of markers ??

Comment: I get the long/lat from the map for each marker and keep it in a list.  The drawing is done via a polygon - I used https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes as a reference.